# Selenium - Focus and Blur fails randomly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium-webdriver, focus, blur

I am testing on Firefox 55.0 Selenium 3.5.3 and I am having some trouble with **Focusing on** input element and after editing the text **focusing out** so the Client side validation can work and **show error** if needed.

```
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').focus();");
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').blur();");
```

this is the actual code.

Problem: The code works fine without any error but fails to show the error on random basis. I have **webDriverWait** for 5 seconds until the error shows up.

Any reason my code is failing on Firefox randomly???

Answer (score 2):

Are you running multiple test with firefox simultaneously? If so, you could try to enable the flag focusmanager.testmode on the firefox profile. Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974538/multiple-instances-of-firefox-during-selenium-webdriver-testing-not-handling-foc/48828244#48828244) for more details.

Comment: No.It was Multiple tests on 1 browser instance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Geckodriver to talk to the firefox instance?

I believe it has to do with the fact that Geckodriver does not start firefox with -foreground option.

Can you try adding
        firefoxOptions.addArguments("-foreground");